# How to show all LaTeX code but still have set conceallevel=3 for vim-devicons and NERDTree?

Tags: vimrc, filetype-tex, plugin-nerdtree

How can I adjust my .vimrc so that `set conceallevel=0` is specific to just LaTeX documents?

The plugin `vim-devicons` requires the following conceal level with NERDTree:

```
set conceallevel=3
```

However, with this level set to 3, when editing a LaTeX document the LaTeX code is hidden and its WYSIWYG form is shown instead.

For example, instead of this showing in Vim:

```
\textbf{Leading Word:} This is a sentence.
```

...this is shown in Vim instead:

> **Leading Word**: This is a sentence.

It's quite annoying to say the least because I would rather see the code, (or at least have the code revealed with the cursor placed over the text if there's no solution to see just the code with a conceallevel=3).

Setting `set conceallevel=0` in my .vimrc has no effect on the LaTeX document and it continues the WYSIWYG behavior.
Setting in vim `set conceallevel=0` is cumbersome to do by hand in my workflow, and all the icons have special characters and brackets surrounding them.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to my own question after hours of hunting.

This post sheds light on the issue: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160953/disable-latex-symbol-conversion-in-vim

It's resolved by:

```
let g:tex_conceal=""
```

To quote `h: tex_conceal`:

> ```
>               *g:tex_conceal*  Tex: Selective Conceal Mode~
> ```
>
> You may selectively use conceal mode by setting g:tex_conceal in your
>   <.vimrc>.  By default, g:tex_conceal is set to "admgs" to enable
>   concealment for the following sets of characters: >
>
> a = accents/ligatures   b = bold and italic     d = delimiters  m = math
>   symbols   g = Greek   s = superscripts/subscripts < By leaving one or
>   more of these out, the associated conceal-character substitution will
>   not be made.

Setting this to blank will reveal all the characters hidden specifically for TeX documents.